# DSM6 : Configure Nginx for Wordpress permalinks (avoid 404)

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, synology, nginx-location

With the Synology DSM6 update, we have now to use Nginx instead of Apache. By default Nginx configuration don't allow wordpress permalinks (generate 404).

I read the idea was to transform the /uri in /?p=$uri and put this configuration in the "location" section of the server nginx config.

Where to put this configuration in DSM6 exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the user config? Just copy your working:

```
/etc/nginx/app.d/server.webstation-vhost.conf
```

to:

```
/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/httpd-vhost.conf-user
```

and rename the `server.webstation-vhost.conf` to `server.webstation-vhost.conf.old` or something and restart nginx (`nginx -s reload`)

Or better yet, remove your virtual host(s) from webstation. Only thing is you need to manually update your SSL certs when they expire instead of using the web interface.

Comment: Indeed, I use /etc/nginx/site-enabled (which is a symb link to the directory you mentioned). I even create a symb link for each vhost builded manually. I don't trust Synology anymore who can break everything after an update.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can add custom directives easily, without modifying the DSM behavior.

Take a look at the content of `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/httpd-vhost.conf-user`, to see where the custom configuration has to be stored:

```
server {
    [...]
    server_name NAME
    [...]

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/778943ad-0dc4-40ae-bb7f-7b2285e3203b/user.conf*;
}
```

Then, you just have to create the file `/usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/778943ad-0dc4-40ae-bb7f-7b2285e3203b/user.conf.wordpress-permalink` with the following content:

```
location /{
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

and restart nginx:

```
synoservicecfg --restart nginx
```

It will not break the future DSM update (since it is a supported customization)

Comment: "778943ad-0dc4-40ae-bb7f-7b2285e3203b" seems to be something generated, maybe only once but really, its ugly. I do all manually now without "DSM magic configuration".

Comment: Yes, the tag is automatically generated, but this is a convenient way to insert customization while maintaining the compatibility for the next upgrades. However, replacing the configuration file is also right, I agree. It depends on your preference